# Airflow KubernetesPodOperator image pull policy pull if different SHA digest

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

Currently using KubernetesPodOperator with default_image_policy (`IfNotPresent`). Will be using static tag IDs for different environments. For example, in dev env, the tag will be `dev`, in qa env, the tag will be `qa`, and so on. The issue is if there is actually a new version (different sha digest) of the image but same tag ID. I can change the image policy to `Always` but then it will download all the time. The Airflow DAG contain several tasks that uses KubernetesPodOperator of the same image and I don't want an image downloaded always for each of the task runs.

Is there an image policy that checks the `sha` digest(instead of tag ID) if exists and downloads it if not?

Comment: `imagePullPolicy: Always` is no as inefficient as it seems. If an image already exists, the pull happens almost instantly, because the image layers are cached and no image download is needed in reality.

Answer (score -2):

In the containers image definition you can specify the `sha` to be sure it pulls/uses the correct one.  For example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ubuntu
spec:
  containers:
  - name: ubuntu
    image: ubuntu@sha256:bc2f7250f69267c9c6b66d7b6a81a54d3878bb85f1ebb5f951c896d13e6ba537
    command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "--" ]
    args: [ "while true; do sleep 30; done;" ]
```

or for Airflow KubernetesPodOperator you can use:

```
example = KubernetesPodOperator(
    image=ubuntu@sha256:bc2f7250f69267c9c6b66d7b6a81a54d3878bb85f1ebb5f951c896d13e6ba537,
    task_id="example_task",
    ...
)
```